# Finding library details based on user search input - using LIMIT and OFFSET

Tags: php, mysql, limit, offset

Basically I have 4 fields in a form. I want to the user search for books in a library by either title, or by author or both.  I also want the user to set the length of the list of items and from the starting point, these are not restrictions though the user does not have to specify.

Here is the code:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/config.php';
session_start();
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_USERNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

$title = $_GET["title"];
$authors = $_GET["authors"];
$st = $_GET["start"];
$ln = $_GET["length"];



$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT title, authors, description, price FROM books  WHERE title = :title LIMIT :length OFFSET :start");
$stmt->execute(array(':title' => $title,':start' => $st,':length' => $ln));


while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$title = $row['title'];
$authors = $row['authors'];
$description = $row['description'];
$price = $row['price'];
}


echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Title</td>";
        echo "<td>$title</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Authors</td>";
        echo "<td>$authors</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Description</td>";
        echo "<td>$description</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Price</td>";
        echo "<td>$price</td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";
```

So far it literally just returns me what I have typed in the input - so nothing much at all! Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

Adapt your code this way:

```
echo "<table>";
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$title = $row['title'];
$authors = $row['authors'];
$description = $row['description'];
$price = $row['price'];

echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Title</td>";
        echo "<td>$title</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Authors</td>";
        echo "<td>$authors</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Description</td>";
        echo "<td>$description</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Price</td>";
        echo "<td>$price</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

to print all the rows returned by the query. Your code was printing just the last row.

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful but now it returns nothing at all.

Comment: what do you get? what kind of errors? have you tried your query in mysql to see if it returns any result?